# Writing tests for grizzly sever with jersey with jar dependency

Tags: java, intellij-idea, server, jersey, grizzly

I start the server from the terminal via the `java -jar target/test-service-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` command

However when running tests from Intellij Idea, I just cannot figure out how to start the server..

This is the current code, which doesn't work

```
private HttpServer server;
private WebTarget target;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // start the server
    server = Main.startServer();
    // create the client
    Client c = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(JacksonFeature.class).build();
    // uncomment the following line if you want to enable
    // support for JSON in the client (you also have to uncomment
    // dependency on jersey-media-json module in pom.xml and Main.startServer())
    // --
    // c.configuration().enable(new org.glassfish.jersey.media.json.JsonJaxbFeature());

    target = c.target(Main.BASE_URI);
}
```

This is my startServer code

```
public static HttpServer startServer() {
        // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers

    ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.test.service").register(JacksonFeature.class);
    EncodingFilter.enableFor(rc, GZipEncoder.class);
    rc.register(LoggingFilter.class);
    rc.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    rc.register(CORSResponseFilter.class);
   // rc.property("config", configParams);
    // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
    // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
    HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    //httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(shh);
    return httpServer;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should just start by itself. But for testing you probably want to control when it starts. You can pass `false` as the [third argument to the server factory method](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.9/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/httpserver/GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.html#createHttpServer(java.net.URI,%20org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig,%20boolean)). That way you control when it should start.

You can call `start` and `stop` on the `HttpServer` instance in your before and after methods in your test. You'll need to update the code in the `Main` class also, to call `start()`.

You might also want to check out [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html). Here you won't need to start and stop any servers. The framework will handle it for you. It also makes your tests more configurable than your current set up. Say you only want one resource registered or you want to inject some mocks services. Personally, I would go with the test framework.